# Put image in image with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to integrate one logo in picture which is uploaded from user before to send it to the server. I want to edit picture not just to show the pictures one over other. Is there any way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: the only solution I know is using canvas...( why not edit the picture in server before saving ? _)

Comment: What do you use for the actual upload?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you're trying to add a watermark to an image, so this might be what you're looking for: http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/watermarkjs/